# How to add key value to ModelSerilzer response

Tags: django-rest-framework

using the model

```
class PlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        fields = ("id", "name", "amount")
```

using `ListAPIView` (since only /GET/ operation is valid on this resource)

```
class PlanList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Plan.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlanSerializer
```

for /GET/

```
  [
        {
            "id": 4, 
            "name": "free", 
            "amount": 110.0
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "name": "permium", 
            "amount": 60.0
        }
    ]
```

there is a constant value `DISCOUNT` to be send in the response which should appear only once in the response , so that response looks like

```
  [
        {
            "id": 4, 
            "name": "free", 
            "amount": 110.0
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "name": "permium", 
            "amount": 60.0
        },
       {"DISCOUNT": 210}
    ]
```

I tried to make the this discount as a property and using it in serializer
but this was getting repeated for each instance, I want it to appear just once.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: You mean to say add a dictionary `{'DISCOUNT':210}` to the list of dictionaries  in the response because without that, it would be an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add another dictionary to the `ModelSerializer` response, you can override the `list()` method of the `PlanList` view.

```
class PlanList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Plan.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlanSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(instance)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, many=True)

        serializer_data = serializer.data # get the default serialized data 
        serializer_data.append({"DISCOUNT": 210}) # add a custom dictionary in the response
        return Response(serializer_data)
```

Then, you response will look something like:

```
 [
        {
            "id": 4, 
            "name": "free", 
            "amount": 110.0
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "name": "permium", 
            "amount": 60.0
        },
       {
            "DISCOUNT": 210
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `list method` from `ListAPIView`. Appending your `CONSTANT` to the final serializer data.

```
class PlanList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Plan.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlanSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        #add your constant here
        final_response = serializer._data.copy()
        final_response["DISCOUNT"] = 210
        return Response(final_response)
```

Comment: using djangorestframework==3.0.2, update method not supported, tried extend and append with no success.

Comment: getting ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required at line final_response = dict(serializer.data)

Comment: @naveenyadav check again plz.

Comment: copy is also not supported on serializer.data (type: ReturnList).. supported methods are ['append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'serializer', 'sort']

Comment: use `_data` instead of `data`. Check again.