# Django Rest Framework: How to pass extra argument to django serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a variable named `email` in view.

I want to access this in `ManageSerializer`.

How can I pass this argument in serializer and get there?

**views.py**

```
email = 'xyz@gmail.com' 
interviewData = Manage.objects.
    filter(catcher_id = userCheck['id'], acceptation = '1').
    filter(invitation_date__gte = dateToday)[:5];
serializer = ManageSerializers(interviewData, many = True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841993/2282638

Comment: Why is there a semicolon in python ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add key value to ModelSerilzer response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825236/how-to-add-key-value-to-modelserilzer-response)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe pass it as kwargs:

```
 ManageSerializers(interviewData, many = True, email= email)
```

You can access this in the init of the Serializer, using something like:`kwargs.pop('email')`

OR

You can pass the context to the Serializer like this.

```
 ManageSerializers(interviewData, many = True, context={'email': email})
```

and you can access the context in Serializer like `self.context['email']`

Answer (score 5):

You should pass it in `context` variable:

```
serializer = ManageSerializers(interviewData, many=True, context={'email': email})
```

Docs: [Including extra context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)